# Change icon in Header Navigation menu - SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I need to change icon in the header Navigation Menu. I would like to customize the icon for "Master Data Display".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in the navigation menu, including the icons can be managed with the [ShellUIService](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService).

To change the icon you must call [setHierarchy](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService/methods/setHierarchy)`( aHierarchyLevels )` with the list of items that should be shown in the menu.

`aHierarchyLevels` is structured as follows:

```
[
    {
        title: "Main View",
        icon: "sap-icon://documents",
        intent: "#Action-sameApp"
    },
    {
        title: "View 2",
        subtitle: "Application view number 2",
        intent: "#Action-sameApp&/View2/"
    },
    {
        title: "View 3",
        subtitle: "Application view number 3",
        intent: "#Action-sameApp&/View3/"
    }
]
```